# Prove $H^{s} \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $s > n$ where $H^{s}$ is the Hausdorff Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I have been reading the book Modern Real Analysis by Ziemer and have come to an exercise that I am having trouble with. The exercise is in the chapter on measure theory in the section describing the Hausdorff measure. The exercise statement goes :

> Show that $H^{s} \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $s > n$.

Here $H^{s}$ is the Hausdorff measure with dimension $s$.

There is a theorem included in the text.

**Theorem 4.39**

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $0 \leq s < t < \infty$. Then :

1. If $H^{s}(A) < \infty$ then $H^{t}(A) = 0$
2. If $H^{t}(A) > 0$ then $H^{s}(A) = \infty$

There is also the exercise that immediately precedes it.

**Exercise 4.7.2**

For $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, use the isodiametric inequality to show that :
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{*}(A) \leq H^{n}(A) \leq \alpha(n)\left( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} \right)^{n} \lambda^{*}(A)
\end{equation}
Here :
\begin{equation}
\alpha(s) = \frac{\pi^{\frac{s}{2}}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{\pi}{2} + 1 \right)}
\end{equation}
Where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function. $\lambda^{*}$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Here is my solution so far :

We know by exercise 4.7.2 :
\begin{equation} 
\lambda^{*}(A) \leq H^{n}(A) \leq \alpha(n) \left( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} \right)^{n} \lambda^{*}(A) 
\end{equation}
So :
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{*}(A) = \infty \Rightarrow H^{n}(A) = \infty
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{*}(A) = 0 \Rightarrow H^{n}(A) = 0 
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{*}(A) \in (0,\infty) \Rightarrow H^{n}(A) \in (0,\infty)
\end{equation}
So by theorem 4.39 :
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{*}(A) = 0 \Rightarrow H^{n}(A) = 0 \Rightarrow H^{s}(A) = 0 \; \forall s > n \; \checkmark
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{align}
\lambda^{*}(A) \in (0,\infty) 
 & \Rightarrow H^{n}(A) \in (0,\infty)\\
 & \Rightarrow H^{n}(A) < \infty \\
 & \Rightarrow H^{s}(A) = 0 \; \forall s > n \; \checkmark
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to prove that it works when $\lambda^{*}(A) = \infty$ and $H^{n}(A) = \infty$. Can someone help with this ?

Comment: You know that $\lambda^* = CH^n$. So, in particular, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has  $\lambda^*(A) < \infty$, then $H^s(A) = 0$ for $s > n$. Since $\mathbb {R}^n$ is a countable union of such $A$, we get $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) = 0$.